# get the source of image when user clicks it in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8

i have included four photos in xaml code as follows

```
<Image Grid.Column="0" 
       Source="Assets/1.png"
       Name="m1"
       MouseLeftButtonDown="selected"/>
<Image Grid.Column="1" 
       Source="Assets/2.png"
       Name="m2"
       MouseLeftButtonDown="selected"/>
<Image Grid.Column="2" 
       Source="Assets/3.png" 
       Name="m3"
       MouseLeftButtonDown="selected"/>
<Image Grid.Column="3" 
       Source="Assets/4.png" 
       Name="m4"
       MouseLeftButtonDown="selected"/>
```

i want to get the source of the image in "selected" function.
my selected function is as follows

```
private void selected(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //do somethings....
}
```

How can i assign the source of the selected image(sender) to a new Image object?.
something similar to follows

```
Image newimage = new Image();
newimage.Source = //something..
```

Is there a way to dynamically get the source?

Comment: Well, the sender is going to be your image, so you just need to cast it to an image.

Comment: @mason is right: `Image img = (Image)sender;` or `Image img = sender as Image;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cast your sender as an image and you will be able to use the Source property:

```
private void selected(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Image newimage = new Image();
    newimage.Source = ((Image)sender).Source;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use OriginalSource property of event and cast it to Image:

```
var clickedImage = (Image)e.OriginalSource;
Image newimage = new Image();
newimage.Source = clickedImage.Source;
```